# AngularJS routing: detect if route/state is linked to or directly entered as url

Tags: angularjs

Essentially how can I detect whether a specific route has been linked to from within an Angular application or accessed directly from a user typing that URL into the address bar from within the configuration phase?

I know I can listen for the `$locationChangeSuccess` event like follows:

```
$Scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(evt, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    // -- do something with oldUrl --
});
```

on either `$Scope` or `$rootScope` but these instances are not available during the configuration phase.

Maybe I am making this more complicated than it needs to be but any help would be much appreciated.

### Update

To give some context. Some of the routes in my application load the associated template into a modal window instead of into a standard view. I am using `ui-router` with the basic configuration below:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('index', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'index.html'
});
$stateProvider.state('foo', {
  url: '/foo',
  views: {
    '': {
      template: '='
    },
    modal: {
      templateUrl: 'modal.html'
    }
  }
});
```

}
]);

And the main template:

```
<div class="main" ui-view></div>
<div ui-view="modal"></div>
```

This works fine if the user accessed `/foo` via a link (`ui-sref="foo"`) however the problem I have is that if the `/foo` route is entered directly into the address bar the underlying template does not exist obviously. I could manually set it if the page is accessed in this way instead. So if I can tell where the request has come from then I can set the template accordingly but it needs to be done in the configuration phase above (at least I think it does).

Note that if I were set the template explicitly it would be reloaded on each request to `/foo` which is not the desired result.

Comment: can interpret question several ways...user has not been on application page at all, and you want to know entrance point or user already on page and you want to know if the changed hash in url. Either way it's not clear what your higher level objective is

Comment: Sorry for any confusion I was trying to keep it simple I guess. I've updated the question with the context of the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a solution, but i'm not sure it will make sense in the context of your application.

You could have the `foo` route be a sub route of the index route:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
    });
    $stateProvider.state('index.foo', {
        url: '/foo',
        views: {
            'modal@': {
                templateUrl: 'modal.html'
            }
        }
    });
});

<div ui-view></div>
<div ui-view="modal"></div>
```

The 'downside' of this method is that if you need to reuse the modal in any other part of the application, you need to redefine the state declaration for each of the top level state you need them in.

If you find a better solution, please ping this answer, as i'm trying to solve a very similar problem.

Comment: I had a play with absolute targeting but couldn't quite get the required result but you're right it might just be a matter of making the state declarations more explicit and less "dynamic" which to be honest from a maintainability perspective might not be such a bad idea.

Comment: Have you had a read of the page on [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) in the ui-router wiki? It made more sense after i read through each of the examples there.

I kind of wish there was an easier way to do dynamic routes like this. The best i've come up with is to use the new [$stateNotFound](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) event and dynamically adding a route then if it matches what i want. But that just feels like using an error document as a routing mechanism...